# Receiving error with converting variable to binary in ruby with to_s(2)

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to convert a string into a binary:

```
puts "Tell me a number:"
num1 = gets
puts "The number you gave in binary is " + num1.to_s(2)
```

But I get a "wrong number of arguments (1 to 0)" error.

Any suggestion on how to proceed?

Comment: Hint: what does the `s` in `gets` stand for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert the string you get to a number first

```
puts "The number you gave in binary is " + num1.to_i.to_s(2)
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to use [Kernel#sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) with the `b` field type.

```
sprintf("%b", gets)
```

For example,

```
sprintf("%b", "34\n")
  #=> "100010"
```

This can also be written

```
"%b" % gets
```

You could therefore write the following.

```
puts "Tell me a number:"
puts "The number you gave in binary is %b" % gets
```

If the user entered `"34\n"` this would print

```
The number you gave in binary is 100010
```

Comment: I'm astonished that this works, but it makes sense in a weird way.

Comment: @tadman, I thought `chomp` might be needed, but no; it's similar to how `to_i` works in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

The `to_s` method exists for a lot of things, and some of those things take arguments, some don't. For example, on a String it doesn't, but on an Integer it does.

To convert to binary you'll need to convert that input string to an integer and *then* convert to a binary value as a string:

```
binary = input.to_i.to_s(2)
```

The `to_i` method also takes arguments if you need to convert back from binary into an integer:

```
decimal = binary.to_i(2)
```